# Pick Renditions Ribbon button disabled in EditPost.aspx

Tags: 2013, blog, image-rendition

we are using a Blog in our SP2013 Intranet site and would love to use the Image Rendition in it.
Everything is configured (Blob Cache, Publishing Feature etc..., I am Sitecollection Admin) and works well on regular Page content, but when I am creating or editing a Blog Post and try to Resize an Image with the PickRenditions Ribbon Button, it is grayed out.

I have searched in many forums where other people are complaining about that, EditPost.aspx and disabled Image Rendition Ribbon button, issue, but I never found a solution for it.

Are there any ideas to get this working?